# Comunicacion entre sitio web asp y en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, asp

Tengo un sitio web creado en asp y me han pedido crear un nuevo sitio, que con el tiempo sustituira al actual, con un lenguaje vb.net.
Mientras conviven los dos sitios necesito pasar datos entre los dos sitios como son los valores delo login. La página de login esta escrita en asp.
Por lo que he podido leer se puede realizar la comunicación con una querystring pero me parece que es demasiado inseguro. He estado probando creado una cookie en el sitio asp y luego intentar leerlo en en el sitio vb.net y no logro leerlo y no se donde está el error.

En el sitio asp creo la cookie así:

```
Response.Cookies("nombre") = "Nombre"
Response.Cookies("contrasena") = "Contrasena"
```

En el sitio vb.net intento leerlo así:

```
Dim nombre= Request.Cookies("nombre").Value 
nombre.text=nombre
```

¿Alguna idea por lo que no funciona la lectura de la cookie o alguna otra manera para realizar la comunicación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final después de varias pruebas opté por crear una queryString enviando los datos pero encriptandolos mediante una función que he creado. No es la mejor solución pero es la única que he logrado que funcione para lo comunicación entre los dos proyectos en diferentes lenguajes.

Answer (score 0):

Si, si si.  Absolutamente inseguro.  Debes usar la variable `$Session`.

la pagina que manda debe tener una intruccion como:

```
Session["mi_dato"] = variable_enviada;
```

y la pagina que recibe debe tener una instruccion como:

```
variable_que_recibe = (string)(Session["mi_dato"]);
```

referencias:

- [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)
- [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zg1P97J12Rk)

Comment: Por las pruebas que he hecho y he leido creo no puedo usar las variables de sesion en este caso o al menos no logro hacer que se reconozcan. Ya que una sesión esta en asp y luego cuando intento leerla en vb.net me dice que no existe esa variable.